# In(Mazento) Zend..How Can I Pass String(Some Text) from Controller to View in Redirect URL

Tags: zend-framework, magento-1.7

I used Like this But This is not Working 
$msg=array('id' =>'Account Sucessfully Deleted');
$this->_redirect('customer/account/dresshoheaccount',$msg);
i want $msg Print in My Page,

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do this as follows :

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Account Sucessfully Deleted'));
```

Please note that insert this line before you laid your layout.

you can call this is template as :

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

If not helping, try to add messages not to `catalog/session`, but to `core/session`.

Comment: can you please accept the ans, so anybody else can get benefit of it.